# Set the value of a variable based on the value of another variable php

Tags: php, mysql, variables

New to programming and looking for help please,

i need to the set the value of $b_num based on the value of $egg_type i have tried using an if statement but not having any luck

`

```
 $egg_type = $row["egg_type"] ;
                           
                          if ($egg_type == 'M/S Select Farm')
                          {
                             $b_num = '1';
                          }
                          
                           if ($egg_type = 'Free Range')
                          {
                             $b_num = '1';
                          }
                           
                           if ($egg_type = 'Barn')
                          {
                             $b_num = '2';
                          }
                          
                           if ($egg_type =='Intensive')
                          {
                             $b_num = '3';
                          }
                          
                          if ($egg_type == 'Organic')
                          {
                             $b_num = '0';
                          } 
                          if ($egg_type == 'Brioche')
                          {
                             $b_num = '3';
                          }
```

`

Tried the if statement but the value didnt change,

Comment: You're using quite a few `=` when you intend to write `==`. The first is an assignment, and the second does a comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you've to check if your $egg_type variable is being set in order not to make errors later
Second you can do it like this

```
if(isset($egg_type)) {
if(in_array($egg_type, ['M/S Select Farm', 'Free Range'])) {
    $b_num = 1;
} elseif(in_array($egg_type, ['Intensive', 'Brioche'])) {
    $b_num = 3;
} elseif($egg_type === 'Organic') {
    $b_num = 0;
} elseif($egg_type === 'Barn') {
    $b_num = 2;
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i tired this but only got a value for M/S Select Farm and Barn, didnt get a value for intensive im creating a batch code, so the b_num value is echo to form part of the batch code depending on the grade of egg <input type="text" class="form-control" name="batch_code" value="'.$b_num.'-'.$year.'-'.$week.'-'.$day.'" readonly>

Comment: @StuartBird - When you say that it doesn't work, do a `var_dump($egg_type)` and check what it actually contains. We're working kind of blind here. As far as we know, there could be typos in the value, different casing, extra spaces before/after the value and so on.

Comment: the egg_types are set in the database and are selected using an option input inside a form, options are : Organic, M/S Select Farm, Lion Free Range, Free Range, Barn, Lion Intensive, Intensive,  the script i am using builds a batch code with the egg types i need to change it to a number for the variable b_num that forms part of the batch code, so Organic = 0, M/S Select Farm / Lion Free Range / Free Range = 1, Barn = 2 , Lion Intensive / Intensive = 3.

Comment: @M.Eriksson, Thank you sir :) i have just checked the database entries and check the values, for some reason there was a space at the end of the values Lion Free Range & intensive removed the space and the code works perfect, now im not sure why there was a space at the end of the value , the value is posted into the database using a form

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `$egg_type` is null value. Therefore,you can improve your code (PHP 8.0 version) and set default value for b_num like this:

```
 $egg_type = $row["egg_type"] ;

 $b_num = match($egg_type) {
    'M/S Select Farm' => 1,
    'Free Range' => 1,
    'Barn' => 1,
    'Intensive' => 1,
    'Organic' => 1,
    'Brioche' => 1,
    default => 'nothing any value for b_num'

 };
                           
echo $b_num;
```

Comment: This looks the easiest solution but the software i am updating is on php version 5.4  :/

Comment: @StuartBird - Without knowing anything around why your app is still using PHP 5.4, you should do everything you possibly can to get it upgraded. That PHP version _haven't been supported for the last 7+ years_. That means it hasn't gotten _any_ updates, including important security updates since then. Keep using it could actually be a security issue.

Comment: this is something i am looking into i wish there was an easier way to do it as there is lots of pages to update, luckily the application sits on a local server that does not have any internet access.